# i can't show space in formula in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

I use this code to show the sum of my bank

```
if {?Bank} = {Bank.sum} then {#1} else 0
```

I have 6 bank accounts and when the `bank = Bank` has operations, then I show the `sum`and else I do not show anything.

I do not want to show "0" in my report.
I want to show  `" "(space)`, but when I change it to `" "`.

When I do it, I get the error

> A number is required here

How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
if {?Bank} = {Bank.sum} then ToText({#1}) else ""
```

Another option is to use formatting.

Comment: it work. but it show me number with 2 decimal places.i want show me normal

Answer (score 0):

In that case, use:

```
if {?Bank} = {Bank.sum} then ToText({#1},0) else ""
```

The 2nd arg indicates zero decimal points. See online documentation of the `ToText()` function.